# LDR instruction as memory jump

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m

I'm looking at assembler code and I found one instruction that I don't understand purpose of - `ldr PC, r1`. As far as I understand this performs a memory jump to the value contained at the address pointed to by r1. Why not use B or BL instruction? Will the LDR instruction stall the pipeline? And out of pure curiosity what might happen if the pipeline is not stalled?

Comment: I assume that's `ldr pc, [r1]`. As such it's an indirect jump via a pointer in memory. Neither `b` nor `bl` can do that.

Comment: it could be mov pc, r1, one or the other ldr pc, [r1]

Comment: @Jester Sorry, I missed the zero at the end if this change anything -  `ldr PC, r1, 0`

Comment: I see it commonly in switch case compilation, used with offset and shift.

Comment: @KRol You mean `ldr pc, [r1, #0]`? It's the same as `ldr pc, [r1]`

Answer (score 1):

One reason is that the ARM's branch commands can't branch to an address more than 4 kilobytes away from the current program counter. (I'm not familiar with newer ARM-based machines, just the Game Boy Advance, it has that limitation but I'm not sure about m-Cortex)

Answer (score 0):

Global functions' addresses are in a table in memory. Or there may be simply a table of jump addresses.

```
    adr     r1, jumptable
    ldr     r2, [r1, r12, lsl #2]!
    blx     r2

    ldr     pc, [r1, #4]



jumptable:
    .word   0x80000000
    .word   0x800000c0
    .word   0x800000e0
```

The routine above will first branch (with link) to the `r12`th subroutine then  branch (without link) to the next one in the table upon returning.

---

Most functions start with preserving the registers upon being called:

```
push    {r4-r10, lr}
```

then restore the registers when returning by:

```
pop     {r4-r10, lr}
```

and finally return to the caller by:

```
bx      lr
```

But more likely the restoring and actual return will be combined like:

```
pop     {r4-r10, pc}
```